# Structure returned data from mysql_get_assoc

Tags: php, mysql

I managed to solve my problem with `getAll` and loop after it. But as I'm not very good with mysql queries and such, I decided to ask you if there's a way to get using `getAssoc` from  table:

```
A | B | C
1 | 2 | 3
1 | 3 | 4
```

an array with structure:

```
$array[1][2]=3
      [1][3]=4
```

Comment: show us your current PHP/MySQL code, we can't guess it.

Comment: My question is can we get that array from that table with get assoc only by playing with the query. (My code works but I dont use get_assoc and I use loops(and i'd like to avoid them if I can))

Comment: so you want to create an array of results using column1 for the first index, column2 for the second and containing the value of column3? Your doing something like $array[$data[0]][$data[1]]=$data[2]; ?

Comment: What is "getAssoc"? It is not a PHP function.

Comment: it pears getAssoc like mysql_fetch_assoc()

Comment: @Waygood: Thanks. The question didn't provide this information.

Comment: Sorry no luck here! getAssoc will only do an array with first field as in index, not the second one too! Your going to have to iterate through it either with getRow, getAssoc etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want

```
$output = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   $first_col = $row['A'];
   $second_col = $row['B'];
   $third_col = $row['C'];
   $output[$first_col][$second_col] = $third_col;
}
```

Also remember, don't use `mysql_*`, PHP isn't supporting it anymore. Better to switch to [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT A,B,C FROM TABLE_NAME');

$out = array();
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 $out[] = array($row['A'] => array($row['B']=>$row['C'])); 
}
```